# How do I stop Json.Parse() from instantiating classes found in the stringified object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, class, sockets

Here's my situation: I'm using the MEAN stack, and on my Angular front-end I'm creating instances of classes and putting them into an array of arrays which are all inside a gameMap/mapData object.  I'm then stringifying and sending this object via a socket connection to my back-end, which broadcasts the object to other connected clients so they can see the current game state.

It seems like everyone else having issues with JSON.parse() wants it to instantiate classes, but I am having the opposite problem.  When a client receives this game object via sockets and then tries to JSON.parse() the object, it seems to be automatically instantiating classes from the data, which causes the problem of running the constructor on those classes, overwriting the class attributes with the constructor defaults.  How can I stop JSON.parse from instantiating these classes and instead have it just create objects with types?

To illustrate that I am getting the correct data in my stringified JSON object but the issue is when it gets parsed, I put a console.log immediately before and after the JSON.parse() of my incoming data.  This code looks like this:

```
console.log('got existing map data, beginning processing:', mapDataRaw);
var mapData2 = JSON.parse(mapDataRaw);
console.log('parsed mapData:', mapData2);
```

In the first console log, I get the correct changed values, as shown below (edited and shortened the returned object because it is huge):

```
{"location":{"row":1,"col":0,"rotate":180,"transform":"rotate(180deg)"},"hp":50,"speed":4,"range":6,"ammo":0,"shieldHP":0,"size":50,"border":"","team":"blue","moved":false,"imgAlpha":"1","name":"Fighter","missile":{"firing":true,"target":{"row":4,"col":3}},"img":"assets/img/playerShip1_blue.png","imgTop":{"img":"assets/img/Power-ups/pill_yellow.png","alpha":1,"transform":"","size":22}}
```

As you can see, the ammo is set to 0 and inside the missile attribute the firing attribute is set to true.  However, this is the section of this object in the console log after the parse:

```
0: Fighter
location: {row: 1, col: 0, rotate: 180, transform: "rotate(180deg)"}
hp: 50
speed: 4
range: 6
ammo: 1
shieldHP: 0
size: 50
border: ""
team: "blue"
moved: false
imgAlpha: "1"
name: "Fighter"
missile: {firing: false, target: {…}}
img: "assets/img/playerShip1_blue.png"
__proto__: BaseObj
```

Note that the ammo is 1 and in the attribute missile, the attribute firing is false.  These are both incorrect and are what these values would be by default at the start of the game.  Also note that it says at index 0 of the array is 'Fighter', which is the name of the class.  How in the world did JSON.parse() know to create it as an instance of the Fighter class when that doesn't seem to be stated anywhere in the raw stringified object attributes (I have 'name' set to the class name but I tried changing this to 'unitName' in case 'name' was some built-in class name thing and that didn't change anything)?  Is there any kind of option I can set to have JSON parse these objects into regular objects instead of instances of classes?  I already have the code written to copy the values from these objects into actual class object instances on the client, but this doesn't work if the values I'm copying from have been overwritten by defaults!

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is definitely not instantiating anything. I don't know what's happening though, the only thing I can think of is that you're seeing live output that got updated. What happens if you do `console.log('parsed mapData:', JSON.stringify(mapData2));`?

Comment: It's theoretically possible that `JSON.parse` function itself is being overwritten somewhere else in your code (scary thought!). To get some more information you could try using the [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function to inspect what `JSON.parse` is doing, like this: `JSON.parse(mapDataRaw, function(k, v) { console.log(k, v); return v; });`

Comment: Whoa Chris G, great idea, and the result is crazy weird.  Here's what it spits out:
`{"location":{"row":1,"col":0,"rotate":180,"transform":"rotate(180deg)"},"hp":50,"speed":4,"range":6,"ammo":0,"shieldHP":0,"size":50,"border":"","team":"blue","moved":false,"imgAlpha":"1","unitName":"Fighter","missile":{"firing":true,"target":{"row":2,"col":0}},"img":"assets/img/playerShip1_blue.png","imgTop":{"img":"assets/img/Power-ups/pill_yellow.png","alpha":1,"transform":"","size":22}}`  So somehow it's stlil got the right data after the parse when you restringify it... wtf is happening?

Comment: Like I said, a browser's console is live. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/5yjaL9x3/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out what was going on, in case anyone runs into a similar situation.  It has to do with JavaScript hoisting I think.  Later in my code I set a different object's map equal to the gameData.map, and then edit values and adjust it. Apparently JavaScript was hoisting all of this adjustment and new object code up to the top ahead of my console.logs, so even though it looked like the values were being changed immediately after the parse, it was actually later that the values were changed.  The root cause was having that other object's map set to be equal to gameData.map, because instead of copying the values, that instead literally pointed to the same objects which caused them to be overwritten in what I thought was the unchanged original.